# Dual polarity (+-12v) from a bench power supply?

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I have an adjustable power supply (TENMA - two channels 30V-3A and one 5V-3A I think) and I want to get a +-12V rail from it.
By putting the supply into series it says that it has internal relays so I assume I don't need to bridge something (right??).
When in series mode I can seem to understand how to get positive and negative 12V potential in respect to the ground...
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

You should wire the power supply like above picture. Put both 30V channels to 12V. Then connect them in series. The wire connecting the - to the + is your reference.

I think you are confusing the ground with your reference voltage. Ground is attached to the wall plug of the power supply which is not the same as your reference voltage.

Comment: you are right, I did confuse the 'ground' with the reference but I think my confusion was amplified because I read in the manual that there is an internal relay in "series mode" and I couldnt found a pair of +,- or ground that I could get +/-12. Ill test with the bridge. thanks. is there problem if there is an internal relay that links the terminal and I bridge them also externally?

Comment: @OHTO In series mode, the outer + and - clamps will be the +12 and -12 supplies. The middle + and - clamps will be your reference. If you measure the voltage, put you return lead in the reference, then measure the voltage with respect to the reference. It should display +12 between + and reference and -12V between refence and -.